# Angular 2 base_href linking assets issue

Tags: laravel, angular, webpack, assets, relative-path

I am using `laravel 5.3` with `angular 2` for my project and using `webpack` for compilation of the assets including `js and css`.

**I am trying to use same `font awesome and bootstrap` for the client and admin area.**

I have the folder structure of laravel with everything inside `js directory`.

```
|-public
   |-js
      |-assets
         |-fontawesome-webfonts.woff
         |-image1.png
      |-vendor.bundle.js
      |-polyfill.bundle.js
```

For Angular 2 routes we need to add the `base href` to the main template which i have also added.

```
<base href="/">
```

Admin url is `localhost:8000/admin`

and user url is `localhost:8000`

I have included the bundles like

```
{!! Html::script('js/vendor.bundle.js') !!}
```

and the vendor have imported the `less` files as:

**vendor.bundle.js**

```
import  'admin-lte/build/less/AdminLTE.less';
import  'font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less';
```

**The main issue is that when i use the same `vendor.bundle.js` to both user and admin pages the user page works fine since it loads the fonts from `js/assets/fontawesome-webfonts.woff` but when i load the admin page it couldn't load the fonts as it searches from `admin/js/assets/fontawesome-webfonts.woff` which is not the correct directory.**

**How could i make Angular search into `js/assets/fontawesome-webfonts.woff` for both url?**

The issue is displayed in the image too.

[image: Assets linking issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out by myself using the `url-loader webpack plugin`.

**You should leave the base href to as it is and configure the assets.**

I just needed to add a new test only for the `fonts`

```
{
    test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=assets/[hash].[ext]&publicPath=/js/'
}
```

You need to specify the `publicPath` and add the other directories to `name`.

That's all. Hope it will save someone's precious time.

**Note: don't forget the '/' at the front of the public path**